# Quick switching between resource files in Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Is there a possibility to open the same file(s) but from other resources in IntelliJ IDEA?

For example, I'm editing the `/layout/main_activity.xml` and would like quickly swith to `/layout-land/main_activity.xml`. Is that possible?

Comment: upvote for good suggestion. try opening a new feature suggestion and try explaining how would you like this feature to work. I think it would be great, but even now I am not sure how will they implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a related feature request, please vote and comment describing your use case and the suggested solution (or submit a new request):

- [IDEA-87590](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87590) editing multiple layout.xml files with the same name

Comment: I think that this is not what he needed. This is just a visual help which has already been implemented.